# Can't make executable portable

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking, compiler-flags

I made a little c++ program with this library: http://libtins.github.io

I compile with: `g++ -o arp arp.cpp -ltins`

It runs fine (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit), however if i send the executable to a friend, he gets this error when running:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtins.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've looked up on stackoverflow and found something about statically linking and dynamically linking, also tried some g++ arguments but no success.

Is it even possible, to create a binary that "contains" the shared object itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-static` to link the libraries statically.

```
g++ -o arp arp.cc -ltins -static
```

To build libtins statically, you could refer to the following section in its [README](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins#staticshared-build):

> #### Static/shared build
>
> Note that by default, only the shared object is compiled. If you would
>   like to generate a static library file, run:
>
> cmake ../ -DLIBTINS_BUILD_SHARED=0

Comment: gives me this error (translated): /usr/bin/ld: unable to find -ltins

Comment: @Matteo You probably have to recompile this library as static lib.

Comment: How could i do that?

Comment: @Matteo Edited to include the README section about static build

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, the binary is 200 times larger though